# Get last item of an array in elasticsearch

Tags: arrays, elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I've being putting my apache log to elasticsearch via logstash so I can use it at kibana

My question is about the request uri as a terms array (the one kibana gives you if you use it in a terms panel refered as request.uri for instance)

Is it possible to get the TopN of the last item in this terms array?

If I think in python array (my main language) it will be:

request.uri[-1]

Is there a way to express that in elk stack?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

When you load a string field in ES that is analyzed, it does tokenizing on it and those tokens become the terms (to simplify it slightly).

So those URI terms are the different path components.  If you want to do something smarter with it --  use logstash to add a field that's only the last component -- or mark the field as `not_analyzed` and then treat the whole URI's as terms.